# Reformating blocks of javascript?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I recently downloaded a template that uses a .js file

It has no formatting of any kind and the file is just a single block of code ( pages worth of it ) Are there any ways to automatically reformat the code as it should be? Trying to search for single lines that I need to edit has been a nightmare.

I am a Mac OS user, using Dreamweaver CS5.

Comment: Try https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a block of minified code.
Converting a block of minified code into something that is more easily human readable is known as beautifying - there are many web apps that can help you with this, a google search of "beautify javascript" provides several options

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the first time I've run into a situation quite like this. I assume they've done it purposefully to make it difficult to edit the template, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problems, happy to help. Minifying is usually done to increase website speed FYI. See here: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/why-minify-javascript-code/